# How to inject Service to have a common instance to several clasess them in zend 3

Tags: dependency-injection, zend-framework3, laminas

In Zend 3, I cannot to figure out how should injections work, let me show some simple example.

Let's say, I have

```
class ToolCollector implements ToolCollectorInterface {
    public function __construct(){}
    public function registerTool(ToolInterface $tool){
        $this->tools[] = $tool;
    }
}
```

and also

```
class ToolA implements ToolInterface {
public function __construct(ToolCollectorInterface $mainCollector){$mainCollector->registerTool($this);}
}
```

so what I expect to have

```
class SomeController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function __construct(ToolCollectorInterface $toolCollector){$this->collector=$toolCollector;}
    public function indexAction(){
        new ToolA;    // <- just call Tool and it will put itself in ToolCollector, this is I want
        new ToolB;    // <- just call Tool and it will put itself in ToolCollector, this is I want
        new ToolC;    // <- just call Tool and it will put itself in ToolCollector, this is I want
    
     return ViewModel(['toolNameList'=>$this->collector->getRegisteredToolNames();])
    }
}
```

I tried to make it as shown in example, when i call `new ToolA` it shows me error 500  without any description.

```
// Next is works
class ToolControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $pm = $container->get(ToolCollector::class);
        return new $requestedName($pm);
    }
}

// Next is not reachable, And I do not know why...
class ToolFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $pm = $container->get(ToolCollector::class);
        return new $requestedName($pm);
    }
}
```

In module.config.php

```
return [
...
'service_manager' => [
    'aliases' => [
            ToolCollectorInterface::class => ToolCollector::class,
        ],
        'factories' => [
            Service\ToolCollector::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
],
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\App\SomeController ::class => ToolControllerFactory::class,
    ]
],
...
];
```

Is it possible to do it?
How to write factory to make it possilbe?

Answer (score 0):

You must understand something very easy to spot using IoC Inversion of Control. The `Container` is handling the building process and a reference to the instances you need.

So it is cumbersome and useless, in fact, to make a `new` inside your `indexAction()`.
You should (and, in fact, you must do it to follow best practices) make any `new` inside your factory for each dependency your `SomeController` has.

So you will have many factories. For your Controllers, for your Services, for your  Repositories, etc. Each factory has its own logic to build the object you need.

If there is no deps, you can use the default `InvokableFactory` factory without to write yours. If there is at least one dep, then you must write your own factory with returning your Controller / Service / Repository / etc. class which is built as a ready to use object instance.

The code :

```
class ToolFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $pm = $container->get(ToolCollector::class);
        return new $requestedName($pm);
    }
}
```

I do not see any `ToolFactory` inside your config, only a `ToolControllerFactory` :

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\App\SomeController ::class => ToolControllerFactory::class,
    ]
],
```

So it is normal that is sending you a http 500 error, because it does not know the factory your are trying to use to build your Controller.

Zend Framework / Laminas is very tied to configuration. You must follow principles and then you can build your own path to make the things work. But, much important thing, you must be structured enough to not lose yourself in the forest.

Go step by step without the will to change the world when you are starting to walk. Dreams are necessary. But you have to handle a learning curve firstly, as any of us !